# Apply distinct flags when compiling a subset of the sources

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two sets of source files in my project from which I need to generate object files.

```
SET_ONE = foo.o bar.o
SET_TWO = zerz.o zork.o
```

I want to pass add an extra option to CFLAGS when building the files in SET_ONE but not for those in SET_TWO.  For example, I want:

```
> make -n
cc -c -DEXTRA_FLAG foo.c
cc -c -DEXTRA_FLAG bar.c
cc -c zerz.c
cc -c zork.c
...
```

Since the files have the same extension, the same rule applies to all of them, and I don't see a straightforward way to tweak CFLAGS for just the ones in one of the sets.

I could make custom rules for the files in SET_ONE:

```
foo.o : foo.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DEXTRA_FLAG foo.c

bar.o : bar.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DEXTRA_FLAG bar.c
```

but that leads to repetition, which will be harder to maintain.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?  It's probably been a decade since I hacked on a makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it.  The most straightforward uses [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html); add to your makefile:

```
$(SET_ONE): CFLAGS += -DEXTRA_FLAG
```